# Group Array items in PHP

Tags: php

I have the above array:

```
| Student First Name   |Student Last Name   | Age |Disability|
| Student_First_Name_1 |Student_Last_Name_1 | 30  | 1        |
| Student_First_Name_2 |Student_Last_Name_2 | 28  | 0        |
| Student_First_Name_3 |Student_Last_Name_3 | 21  | 0        |
| Student_First_Name_4 |Student_Last_Name_4 | 20  | 1        |
| Student_First_Name_5 |Student_Last_Name_5 | 22  | 0        |
```

and I want to grouped the students by age and Disability.
So if my code runs correctly I'll have the above results:

Student_First_Name_1 : Student_First_Name_4 
Student_First_Name_3 : Student_First_Name_5 
Student_First_Name_2

But instead I have the above:

Student_First_Name_1 : Student_First_Name_4 
Student_First_Name_3 : Student_First_Name_5 
Student_First_Name_2 : Student_Last_Name_3 
Student_First_Name_2 : Student_Last_Name_5

My code is:

```
    $StudentsForSID = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE sid = :sid AND level = :level");
    $StudentsForSID->execute([ 'sid' => $SelectedSID,  'level' => 'LRN_B1' ]);
    while($row = $StudentsForSID->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $TempSelected[] = $row;
    }
    $count=count($TempSelected);
    for($i=0; $i<$count-1; $i++){
        for ($j = $i+1; $j < $count; $j++) {
            if($TempSelected[$i]['disability']==$TempSelected[$j]['disability']){
                if( abs($TempSelected[$i]['age']-$TempSelected[$j]['age']) <= 23 ){
                    $Student1 = $TempSelected[$j]['first_name'];
                    $Student2 = $TempSelected[$i]['first_name'];
                    print_r($Student1.'-'.$Student2.'<br/>');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't think I explained very well. So i edit the question.
What I want: 
I want to make groups of 2 students with the same value in disability and the age difference between the 2 students to be equal or under 23.

So I have the above array with 5 students. From this array I'll make 3 groups and the groups will be the above (2 groups with 2 students with fulfilled the criteria, and 1 group with one student).

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: what you have want didn't clear ? please explain more.

Comment: I have no idea how you come to your desired result on the basis of grouping by age and disability. And the result you are supposedly getting contains last names, although in the code you have shown you seem to be accessing the first name field only - how is that supposed to make sense? Also, you are checking some age difference for being <= 23, what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: Why not make a querry for "Disability==1", print those ones and then make one querry for "Disability ==0" and print those? Whould that get the desired result?

Comment: This might sound like a pedantic question - but it looks to me that you want to order (as opposed to group) the results by disability - could this be the case? In other words, list disabled first, then show the rest. If so, add an `ORDER BY` clause to your query.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a double group by in your query?

```
Group by Age , Disability
```

This will actually group your results into two groups like you wanted so you will save the php sorting and those multiple `if` and `for`.